# Get specific content off responseText

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, element, responsetext

I am making an ajax call and I get the content from `responseText`.

I confirm by using `alert` that inside, the `responseText` contains the entire page as a `string`.

That's fine. Now I need to extract specific contents from the string by converting it to DOM and using `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByName` etc...

My problem is that none of these seems to work.

I've read many references on using `responseXML` instead of `responseText` but this gives me back `null`.

So, by sticking to `responseText`, how can i get the specific elements that I want?

For instance if my response contains the following:

```
<html>
<head>....</head>
<body>....
 .....
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>sometext</td>
 <td>someothertext</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>sometext</td>
 <td>someothertext</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>sometext</td>
 <td>someothertext</td>
 </tr>    
 </table> 
 <div> somediv </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

how can I access the second row of the table and its value? Or the div etc..
so, now in my actual html, i have sth like this

```
<html>
<head>.....</head>
<body>
<table><tr><td id="test">Test</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

i want the extracted element/value to be parsed inside the table of my actual html..

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = the_extracted_elements_from_responseText

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use a `DOMParser` on the html and use DOM traversal methods on the resulting document to return the desired node(s).

```
  var parser=new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(responseText,"text/xml");
  var tds = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

Note that IE would require `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");` instead.

Comment: about Note that IE would require new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); instead. is this on newer browsers as well..?? cause i thought that this was only necessary on i.e7 and earlier..

Comment: @nikolas I can't find a reference for that but yes off the top of my head IE8+ have `DOMParser`

Comment: i have used document.getElementById('test').innerHTML in my code, and now i get [object Nodelist] shouldn't it just parse the entire td to the specified area?

Comment: @nikolas It isn't entirely clear what you're asking. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: i edited my original post by adding the next part i m talking about..since i m able now to handle some content out of the responseText, how can this content be parsed into my main html file..?

Answer (score 0):

create the variable array and make the push.

```
const result = [];
for(let i = 1; i < ?? ; i++) {
const test = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
result.push({ test })
}
return { result }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;//xhr is your own xhr obj
//select the element u want, such as the follow one
var foo = temp.querySelector('#foo');
```