# AJAX - Grab specific DOM elements from another html file?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to use vanilla JS to get content to load without refreshing. When a menu option is clicked, I would like to get content from another html file, but only grab either the body or a particular class.

Is this doable without jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

```
var AJAX = function(page){

  var call = new XMLHttpRequest();

  call.open("GET", page);

  call.send();

  call.addEventListener("load", function(e){
    console.log(e.target.responseText); // this shows all the HTML as text, but I only want to grab either the body or a particular class, and use it in an innerHTML method.
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `XMLHttpRequest`, it's pretty easy - with the `responseType` as `document`, the instiantiated `XMLHttpRequest`'s `.response` property will contain the response *document*, which you can use ordinary DOM methods on. For example, the following code will select and log the text of the first element with a class name of `foo` from the response document:

```
function get(url){
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
  r.open('GET', url, true);
  r.responseType = 'document';
  r.onload = function () {
    if (r.readyState !== 4 || r.status !== 200) return;
    // also handle error statuses

    // now, r.response is a document:

    const doc = r.response;
    console.log(doc.querySelector('.foo').textContent);
  };
  r.send();
}
```

If you use the more modern `fetch` method, you'll have to convert the response text into a document explicitly, possibly with `DOMParser`. For example:

```
function get(url){
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then((text) => {
      const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html')
      console.log(doc.querySelector('.foo').textContent);
    });
}
```

One of the nice things about `DOMParser` is that you can use it to convert *any* (valid) HTML string into a document.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. assign the content to a hidden div. And then query the DOM.
2. parse the response as XML and access the tags.

For 1:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {

           if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
              var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
              ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
           }
        }
```

For 2, this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13460821/1364747